# input data from text file and output that to excel file

Tags: java

I am finding a way that I get the raw data from text file and output that log into formatted excel file like belore. please experts help me to accomplish this by JAVA.

1. text log format is like below. below is just one count of log and in text file more than million counts are existed. 
   mu1RmmeX001 2017-06-17 SAT 00:01:18
   F6100 SUBSCRIBER INFORMATION FAULT
   LOC       = SHELF0/SLOT1-LESA1/CPU0
   INF       = EVENT: ATTACH
   NE   : AUC
   IMSI : 405151002172122
   REASON    = DIAMETER_ERROR_USER_UNKNOWN
   NASCAUSE  = EPS_SERVICES_AND_NON_EPS_SERVICES_NOT_ALLOWED (H'08)
   ;
2. The output format that I want to get is given below.

Comment: Please take a few mins to go through [How to Ask A Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty: don't try to generate an excel file, but simply write to a normal file (for example via BufferedWriter - you will find plenty of information in the net about that!), but do so in CSV (comma separated value) style:

```
VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3
```

If you succeded in doing so, you can read in your 'normal' text file with excel and receive a 'normal' excel file.